# Conception of an application with login

Tags: android

Say I have 4 Activities: `Login`, `Sync`, `Main`, `Details`.

`Main` and `Details` can only be accessed if the user is logged in and passed the synchronization phase. `Main` can be accessed from an icon on the drawer. `Details` can be accessed from `Main` and from the notifications.

The user is logged off after 30 minutes of inactivity (with a timer on a Service).

I am not sure which way I should take to make sure the user is logged in. Here are my two scenarios:

- The icon launches `Login` which checks if the user is logged in, then launches `Synch`, which does the same and launches `Main`.
- The icon launchs `Main` which checks is the user is logged in, if not, launch `Login`. `Login` closes itself to show `Main` that was on the back stack.

And then there is also `Details` that needs to checks if the user is logged in.

The second scenario seems more correct to me, because it allows to launch other Activities than `Main`, but it will force me to duplicate the check code in every Activity that needs to have the user logged in. (I have more than 2 activities).

Why way should I take? Why?

Comment: Why not let your service decide if the user is logged in or not? Every activity you have will bind to your service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend a `BaseActivity` which implements all your checking code, then any new `Activity` you use will have it built in.

I use this in an app which has access to 50% of the Activities without logging in and displays a prompt using `startActivityForResult(...)` to catch the success or failure of the login attempt.

It works really well and keeps everything neatly encapsulated :)

**EDIT**

Here is a code snippet to modify as you wish:

```
/**
 * This is an abstract class that all Activities will be based on.
 */
public abstract class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    protected static final int    SHOW_WALLET       = 100;
    protected static final int    SHOW_OFFER_DETAIL = 101;
    protected static final int    REGISTER          = 102;
    protected static final int    SHOW_ACCOUNT      = 103;

    protected static final int    LOGGED_IN_OK      = 103;
    protected static final int    REGISTERED_OK     = 104;

    protected static final int    DIALOG_DELAY      = 300;
    // for passing data in extras
    protected static final String TEXT_SEARCH       = "text_search";
    protected static final String SEARCH_TERM       = "search_term";

    protected boolean             mAlternateTitle   = false;
    private Dialog                loading;
    private Runnable              showDialog;   

         protected final void openAccount()
        {
            Intent i;
            if ( LoginManager.getInstance().isLoggedIn() )
            {
                i = new Intent( this, MyAccountActivity.class );
                startActivity( i );
            }
            else
            {
                i = new Intent( this, LoginActivity.class );
                startActivityForResult( i, SHOW_ACCOUNT );
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: This sounds like the best solution.

Comment: This seems good. But I will need to make sure that subclasses of BaseActivity do not use the same requestCode as the "login" one.

Comment: Make some protected final int CODE_ACTIVITY_XYZ constants in BaseActivity that they can access. Make BaseActivity abstract too, helps keep things simple.